# The $ sign should move based on the string input

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText, the moment I enter any number, the $ sign should move based on the string input. For example, if I enter 20, the $ sign should move towards right and it should be 20$. If I enter 200, the $ sign should move towards right and it should be 200$. Any help would be highly appreciated.

This is how my code looks as of now:`

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/amount_edit_text"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_normal"
app1:inputTextSize="@dimen/text_large" 
app1:inputIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_dollar_sign"
app1:inputIconTint="@color/colorDark"
app1:inputOneHint="@string/offer_amount"            
app1:inputIconTranslateY="@dimen/offer_large_text_icon_shift"
app1:inputType="number"/>
```

`

Comment: What did you try? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just a semantics question, but doesn't the dollar sign normally reside on the left side of a number? e.g. $200

Comment: @RayfenWindspear: Yes, it does, but, placing it towards the right is what the requirement is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TextView.addTextChangedListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)) to watch for when the text changes. Then you can just attach the $ wherever you want.

EDIT: As Cruncher noted, this may fire another onTextChanged event. So wrap it in an if that checks if it already ends with $.

Something like this:

```
EditText amountEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount_edit_text);
amountEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   }

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // add $ only if we need to
        if (!s.toString().substring(s.length() - 1)).equals("$")) {
            amountEditText.setText(s + "$");
        }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With `addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher)` add a `Textwatcher` to the `EditText`.

Implement `TextWatcher.onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)` like this:

`TextWatcher.onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
     EditText.setText(s + "$");
}`

Comment: Uhm, doesn't changing text in a textwatcher trigger another onTextChanged?